# Create pandas DataFrame from numpy array of dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have very long numpy array that has multiple dictionnaries as elements:

`np.array([{'col1': 'somevalue', 'col2': 2}, {'col1': 'someotherval', 'col2': 4}, {'col1': 'zzzzz', 'col2': 47}], dtype=object)`

Is there any way to create a pandas DataFrame where each dictionary would be a row?

Result should be:

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 'somevalue' | 2 |
| 'someotherval' | 4 |
| 'zzzzz' | 47 |

Also conerting the numpy array to a list would not work as I need to keep memory usage low, so I can't go with
`pd.DataFrame(list(my_array))`

Comment: `pd.DataFrame.from_records(arr)`?

Comment: or `pd.json_normalize(arr)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `iter()` to avoid making an intermediate list:

```py
pd.DataFrame(iter(arr))
```

This outputs:

```py
           col1  col2
0     somevalue     2
1  someotherval     4
2         zzzzz    47
```